# Subsetting Blocks (or Callables in general)

Tags: signature, raku, subtyping

This [question was originally posted by `lookatme` in the Perl6 IRC channel](https://irclog.perlgeek.de/perl6/2018-05-17#i_16174595). The original intention is to [constrain a Callable](https://docs.raku.org/syntax/Constraining%20signatures%20of%20Callables) by [using subsets](https://docs.raku.org/language/typesystem#index-entry-subset-subset) or any other possible way. It works in signatures, however this:

```
subset WalkCb of Callable where *.signature ~~ :(Int $a); 
my WalkCb $x = sub (Int $a) { return $a; };
```

returns

```
«Type check failed in assignment to $x; expected WalkCb but got Sub (sub (Int $a) { #`(Sub...)␤  in block <unit> at <tmp> line 1␤␤»
```

Other variants of the declaration return similar messages. What would be the correct syntax?

Comment: FWIW, I have opened a Rakudo issue about this: https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/1836

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears the `WhateverCode` parsing messes up in this case.  So if you specify a block in the `where`:

```
subset WalkCb of Callable where { .signature ~~ :(Int $) }
my WalkCb $x = sub (Int $a) { return $a; }
```

it appears to work as expected.  Also note that I removed the `;` at the end of the lines, as a `}` at the end of a line is also the end of a statement.  And that I removed the "a" from the signature: the name of of positional parameters in signature smartmatching is ignored.

Answer (score 7):

A `where` constraint can take a block (lambda) or a statement.

```perl6
… where { $_ == 42 }; # block
… where    * == 42;   # lambda
… where   $_ == 42;   # statement
```

The thing is that `~~` doesn't participate in the creation of WhateverCode lambdas (`*`)
So what you are really doing is creating a lambda of `*.signature` inside of a larger `where` **statement** (not lambda).

```perl6
constant $lambda = *.signature;
subset WalkCb of Callable where $lambda ~~ :(Int $);
```

Which will of course never return `True` as the lambda has a signature of `:(;; $ is raw)`

---

So instead just write the statement form. (using implicit `$_`)

```perl6
subset WalkCb of Callable where .signature ~~ :(Int $);
my WalkCb $x = sub (Int $a) { return $a }
say $x(42); # 42␤
```